# Symfony Security Registration and Authentication

Tags: php, security, symfony, authentication, registration

I use UserBundle and HWIO for social network, but If user have not socials I create custom registration, when user have email and password for email I try authentication but have many error last error:

```
    Error: User account is disabled.
```

I don’t know how to be tune service.yml and HWIO still work and standart authentication help please
And know not working enter with HWIO:

```
 Unable to find the controller for path "/login/check-vkontakte". The route is wrongly configured.
```

with this work fine security:

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username
    my_custom_hwi_provider:
        id: app.provider.user_provider


firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        oauth:
            resource_owners:
                facebook:           "/login/check-facebook"
                vkontakte:             "/login/check-vkontakte"

            login_path:        /login
            failure_path:      /login

            oauth_user_provider:
                #this is my custom user provider, created from FOSUBUserProvider - will manage the
                #automatic user registration on your site, with data from the provider (facebook. google, etc.)
                service: app.provider.user_provider

        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true

    login:
        pattern:  ^/login$
        security: false

        remember_me:
            key: "%secret%"
            lifetime: 60 # 365 days in seconds
            path: /
            domain: ~ # Defaults to the current domain from $_SERVER

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

this my security

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512
    PillsBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm:        sha1
        encode_as_base64: false
        iterations:       1
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username
    my_custom_hwi_provider:
        id: app.provider.user_provider

    chain_provider:
        chain:
            providers: [user_db, in_memory]
    user_db:
        entity: { class: UserBundle\Entity\User, property: email }
    in_memory:
       memory:
         users:
            admin_tyty: { password: adminpass_tyty, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }


firewalls:

    admin_secured_area:
        pattern:    /(.*)
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            provider: chain_provider
            login_path: /auth/login
            check_path: /auth/login_check
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            default_target_path: /?r=db
        logout:
            path:   /auth/logout
            target: /
            invalidate_session: false


    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            #csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        oauth:
            resource_owners:
                facebook:           "/login/check-facebook"
                vkontakte:             "/login/check-vkontakte"

            login_path:        /login
            failure_path:      /login

            oauth_user_provider:
                #this is my custom user provider, created from FOSUBUserProvider - will manage the
                #automatic user registration on your site, with data from the provider (facebook. google, etc.)
                service: app.provider.user_provider

        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true

    login:
        pattern:  ^/login$
        security: false

        remember_me:
            key: "%secret%"
            lifetime: 60 # 365 days in seconds
            path: /
            domain: ~ # Defaults to the current domain from $_SERVER

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

and my SecurityController Controller

```
  /**
  * @Route("/auth")
  */
 class SecurityController extends Controller
 {
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="login_route")
 * @Template()
 */
public function loginAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $session = $request->getSession();

    $securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');
    if ( $securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') ) {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('get_all_posts'));
    }

    if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
        $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    } else {
        $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    }

    return array(
        '_last' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
        'error'         => $error,
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have override the registration controller then Just enable the user in FOSUserBundle > RegistrationController class

If not then have a look in to this doc.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html

```
RegistrationController extends BaseController
{
    public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {
        /** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */
        $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.registration.form.factory');
        /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */
        $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');

        $user = $userManager->createUser();
        $user->setEnabled(true);
    }
```